# Android native view not working couchbase lite beta 1

Tags: android, cordova, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am trying to move javascripte views (phonegap project) to native views (android) but the Mapper function doesn't  works with a Couchbase Lite [beta 1] , and view cannot be created.

Code:

```
private int startCBLListener(int suggestedListenPort) throws IOException,
                                                             CouchbaseLiteException {

    Manager manager = startCBLite();
    dbLite=startDatabase(manager, DATABASE_NAME);

    com.couchbase.lite.View viewItems = dbLite.getView(String.format("%s/%s",
                                                                     "client",
                                                                     "docView"));

    viewItems.setMap(new Mapper() {
        @Override
        public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
            Object type = document.get("type");

            if (type.toString()=="CLIE") {
                emitter.emit(type.toString(), document);
            }
        }
    }, "1.1");

    LiteListener listener = new LiteListener(manager, suggestedListenPort);
    int port = listener.getListenPort();
    Thread thread = new Thread(listener);
    thread.start();

    return port;

}
```

A GET request to the CouchDB server gives the following results:
 *http://localhost:5984/[database]/_design/client*
{"status" : 404}

*http://localhost:5984/[database]/_design/client/_view/docView*
{"offset":0,"total_rows":0,"rows":[]}

*Thanks for any help :)*

**Mat2014_**

Answer (score 1):

The best move now is to upgrade to beta2 available here: http://mobile.couchbase.com

It's a best practice to minimize the value, so maybe emit(type.toString(), null)

Comment: I resolved this issue whene i change the (type.toString()=="CLIE") expression  by (type.toString().equals("CLIE")) ,Thanks for giving help :).